# Попарное добавление и удаление полей формы

Tags: javascript, html, форма

Здравствуйте!

Есть форма: http://jsbin.com/obihat/1/edit
В нее по клику на ADD должны добавляться два поля, в верхнюю часть формы и в нижнюю.
При этом возле каждого поля верхней части формы должна быть кнопка delete, по клике на которую будет удаляться и соответствуюшее поле в нижней части формы.

Буду признателен, за любой толчек, подсказку в сторону правильного решения.

**UPDATED**:
конкретизирую вопрос:
Как по нажатию на баттон DELETE в верхней части формы удалить соответсвующее поле в нижней. 
Т.е. изначально, по нажатию на ADD мы сделали appendChild в обе формы, теперь как узнать для какого поля второй формы нужно сделать removeChild наряду с удалением this.parentNode верхней формы?

ps: На данном этапе я при создании полей ставлю им уникальные data-id, и после по ним и удаляю. Но этот тот еще велосипед, сдается мне, что есть что-то более простое и лежит оно на поверхности. Благодарю.

Comment: учите DOM. `insertBefore()`, `appendChild()` и `removeChild()` вам помогут.

http://htmlweb.ru/java/example/dom_child2.php

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Моя вина, нужно было конкретизировать вопрос.
Как удалить или добавить элемент я в общем-то знаю, добавил уточнение вопроса в update поста.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь я вижу, что человек понимает о чем говорит.

Один из вариантов вешать номера к `id'`шникам элементов DOM.

```
var i=0;
function add(){
    // ...
    delete_button.num=i;
    block_with_inputs.id='inputArea'+i;
    i++;
}
```

по клику на кнопку:

```
function del(){
    // ...
    block_with_inputs=document.getElementById('inputArea'+this.num);
    block_with_inputs.parentNode.removeChild(block_with_inputs)
}
```

---

тут я предполагаю, что `input'`ы у вас объединены блоком. Но не что вам не мешает делать тоже для каждого отдельного элемента, где бы они не находились